# Is this recursion?

Tags: c++, function, loops, recursion, definition

I've read this code from Stanford's CS106B class's textbook in the recursion chapter. This recursive function uses loop. Although decomposition happens between recursive calls and the loop merely tries different combinations, does this function still qualifies the definition of recursion?

Brief of output: a code that generate permutations of a string in a set, such as "ABC" --> "ACB", "BCA"....

```
Set<string> generatePermutations(string str) {
  Set<string> result;
  if (str == "") {
     result += "";
  } else {
    for (int i = 0; i < str.length(); i++) {
      char ch = str[i];
      string rest = str.substr(0, i) + str.substr(i + 1);
      for (string s : generatePermutations(rest)) {
        result += ch + s;
      }
    }
  }
  return result;
}
```

Comment: Yes. This code still qualifies to be recursion. What is not clear about it?

Comment: Did you miss the call to `generatePermutations` that is inside `generatePermutations`?

Comment: If a function appears above itself in the call stack, it's recursion. Alternatively, if there's a cycle in the call graph.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Yes, a method that calls itself is the definition of recursion

Answer (score 3):

Yes, it's recursion. It's just a translation of naive algorithm to programming language, and the most naive algorithm for permutations of length n is to fix one element from set and permute the rest (n-1) elements. So yes, algorithm is recursive, so is it's implementation, too.